# I need to stop imap_body from adding line breaks and inserting characters

Tags: php, simplexml, imap, gmail-imap

I am retrieving email in XML ADF format from a gmail account. I am using imap_body to retrieve the emails. Looking at the email account, I can see the emails are received in two ways. The first starts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?adf version="1.0"?>

<adf>
  <prospect status="new">
    <id sequence="1" source=...
```

The second type starts like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?adf version="1.0"?><adf><prospect status="new"><id sequence="1" source=...
```

For the second type, imap_body returns are fixed with to 75 characters. The 75th character is inserted as an equality sign (=). Additionally, the characters 3D are added after the normal equality signs producing:

```
<?xml version=3D"1.0" encoding=3D"UTF-8"?><?adf version=3D"1.0"?><adf><pros=
pect status=3D"new"><id sequence=3D"1" source=3D...
```

I can correct the strings using a loop for the 75th character, but if the 74th character is an equality sign, the equality sign and a space is inserted before the non-inserted equality sign instead.

Ex.

```
<name part=3D"full" type= 
=3D"business"
```

This throws off the count. I though about compensating for that as well, but would like to try here to fix the actual imap_body request if possible.

```
//Retrieve emails, make corrections if needed, convert to array
$inbox = imap_open($cred['host'],$cred['user'],$cred['pass']);
if(!$inbox){
    $output = ['success' => false,'error' => "Unable to connect to host. ".imap_last_error()];
}else{
    /* Get email list */
    $emails = imap_num_msg($inbox);
    /* Cycle through each email based on count */
    if($emails > 0){
        for($key = 1;$key <= $emails;$key++) {
            /* Retrieve the email body */
            $pull = imap_body($inbox,$key);
            $init = str_replace(["\r","\n"],'',stripslashes($pull));
            //Clears the breaks having the = character and clears the added characters 3D
            if(substr($init,14,2) == "3D" && substr($init,75,1) == "="){
                $max = strlen($init);
                $cnt = 75;//First = character occurance
                while($cnt < $max){
                    $init = substr($init,0,$cnt).substr($init,$cnt + 1);//remove =
                    $cnt += 75;//Set for next iteration
                }
                $init = str_replace("3D",'',$init);//Remove additional 
            }
            $data = simplexml_load_string($init);
            $xml[$key] = json_decode(json_encode($data),true);
        }
    }
}
```

The second type of email requires the corrections to be made, but will be off due to the double equal/space issue part way throught the email. Due to these issues, simplexml_load_string fails. Again, correcting from imap_body would be ideal or otherwise I will continue making corrections hoping there will not be more types of issues.

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is 'Quoted Printable' decoding: https://www.php.net/quoted_printable_decode

Comment: @Max - Yes, that did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a Quoted Printable encoding issue